# SQL Regex for an Address

Tags: sql, regex

I have an Address field which is populated like:

> Flat 1
>
> Flat 2
>
> Flat 2a
>
> Flat 3

As you can see, some entries are just numbers and others contain numbers and letters. I would like to sort them via numbers, then letters - that is, I'd like it ordered like above.

Currently I do this:

```
func1(regexp_substr(DemiseUnit, '^[0-9]+'))
func2(regexp_substr(DemiseUnit, '[0-9]+$'))
```

However, this unfortunately causes `Flat 2a` to go to the bottom of the list. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the field always start with "Flat", a space, and then have the number letter combinations?

Comment: Also, what data type is the field?

Comment: No, it may contain just a number, could have a word after it etc. Not sure of data type - I can only query the database (unless there's a way via a query I am uaware of?)

Comment: So how do you want it to sort if the number comes first?  Can you show an example of the out put that might be more representative of your data?

Answer (score 0):

If you always have "Flat ##AA" then you can do

```
Order By Val(Replace(DemiseUnit,"Flat ","")), DemiseUnit
```